# Rasterizer not picking up GL_LINES as I would want it to

Tags: opengl

So I'm rendering this diagram each frame:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44766482/diagramm.png

Basically, each second it moves everything one pixel to the left and every frame it updates the rightmost pixel column with current data. So a lot of changes are made.

It is completely constructed from GL_LINES, always from bottom to top.

However those black missing columns are not intentional at all, it's just the rasterizer not picking them up.

I'm using integers for positions and bytes for colors, the projection matrix is exactly 1:1; translating by 1 means moving 1 pixel. Orthogonal.

So my problem is, how to get rid of the black lines? I suppose I could write the data to texture, but that seems expensive. Currently I use a VBO.

Comment: Have you tried shifting the lines by a half pixel, instead of drawing them right on the dividing line between two pixels? (integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render you columns as quads instead with a width of 1 pixel, the rasterization rules of OpenGL will make sure you have no holes this way.

Comment: That does the trick, but also creates a lot of data. I'll leave the question open for a while longer, maybe someone has a more efficient answer, if not I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Realize the question is already closed, but you can also get the effect you want by drawing your lines centered at 0.5.  A pixel's CENTER is at 0.5, and drawing a line there will always be picked up by the rasterizer in the right place.